# Binding request parameters with view model Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, spring

I am using drag and drop to create a document with simple questions, check boxes and radio buttons.[image] On save button clicked i create a form and append all the dropped elements to that form to serialize it and make an ajax call to get data on server. I can't figure out how to do this correctly because the way i do it i don't get any data on server. This is what i've tried so far:

```
public class DocumentDefinitionViewModel {    
    private String name;
    private DocumentStatus status;
    private Set<DocDefQuestionViewModel> questions;
    private Set<DocDefMultipleSelectViewModel> checkBoxes;
    private Set<DocDefMultipleSelectViewModel> radioButtons;
    //getters and setters
```

}
Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveDocument", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String saveDocument(@ModelAttribute(value="doc")DocumentDefinitionViewModel doc){  
    //save the document on database
}
```

evaluations.js

```
   $('#saveDocDef').click(function(){

        //get the document definition name
        var docName = $('#docName').val();
        if(docName == ""){
            alert("You need to choose a name for the document");
            return;
        }
        //get the selected status
        var docStatus = $('#selectStatus').val();
        if(docStatus == ''){
            alert("You need to select a valid status for the document");
            return;
        }

        //create a form to serialize the defined elements
        //make sure that the form doesn't exist
        $('#frmSubmit').remove();
        //append it to body
        $('body').append('<form id="frmSubmit" action=""></form>');
        //all elements are hidden
        //append the name and the status of the document definition
        $('#frmSubmit').append('<input type="hidden" id="name" name="name" value="'+ docName +'">');
        $('#frmSubmit').append('<input type="hidden" id="status" name="status" value="'+ docStatus +'">');

        /*************************QUESTION****************************/
        //get all questions content
        var questionText = $('.doc-def-quest-text');
        $(questionText).each(function(index){
            $('#frmSubmit').append('<input type="hidden" id="'+ questionText['index']+'" name="questionContent" value="'+ questionText.eq(index).val() +'">');

        });

        /**************************CHECK BOX*************************/

        //get all checkboxes elements content
        var ckbElements = $('.ckbElem');
        //create new checkbox definition for each element   
        $(ckbElements).each(function(index){
            var ckbQuest = $(ckbElements[index]).find('.ckbQuestionText').val();                
            $('#frmSubmit').append('<input type="hidden" id="'+ ckbElements['index']+'" name="question" value="'+ ckbQuest +'">');
            var predefinedAnswers = $(ckbElements[index]).find('.ckbOptions')[0];
            $(predefinedAnswers).each(function(i){
                $('#frmSubmit').append('<input type="hidden" id="'+ predefinedAnswers['i']+'" name="options" value="'+predefinedAnswers.options[i].text +'">');
            });
        });

        /**************************RADIO***************************/
        //get all radio elements content
        var radioElements = $('.radioElem');
        //create new radio definition for each element
        $(radioElements).each(function(index){
            var radioQuest =  $(radioElements[index]).find('.radioQuestionText').val();
            $('#frmSubmit').append('<input type="hidden" id="'+ radioElements['index']+'" name="question" value="'+ radioQuest +'">');
            var predefinedAnswers = $(radioElements[index]).find('.radioOptions')[0];
            $(predefinedAnswers).each(function(i){
                $('#frmSubmit').append('<input type="hidden" id="'+ predefinedAnswers['i']+'" name="options" value="'+predefinedAnswers.options[i].text +'">');
            });
        }); 

        var result = $('form').serialize();
        $( "#results" ).text( result );

        $.ajax({
            url :"/eMuse/admin/saveDocument",
            dataType: 'json',
            accepts :{
                xml : 'text/xml',
                text: 'text/plain'
            },
            data : {request : result},
            success : function(response){
                alert("Success");
            }
        });
    });
```

Query string parameters[image]

Comment: Are you trying to create a hidden form and submit it or is the requirement to display the form on the click?

Comment: I create a hidden form just for submit, because in the document the user may drag more than one simple question,check box, radio button

Comment: @minion I need to know how to bind the parameters with the view model.